# Finding multiple occurrence

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

Here is the table:

```
account no.  cust_id    Month  Installment  Status
5212340001   1002        30    15000         Closed
5212340002   1002        66    25000         Active
5212340003   1007        36    80555         Closed
5212340004   1003        60    30000         Active
```

I want to find the maximum occurrence of cust_id having multiple accounts.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,COUNT(CUST_ID) AS C
FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
GROUP BY CUST_ID
HAVING C=MAX(C);
```

I am getting error. However expected output should be this:

```
cust_id    c
1002       2
```

Comment: FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
     *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @GAURAVSharma that error means you are trying to select from a table that does not exist in the current database you are in. Check the database and verify that the table actually exists. The answer on how write the query to get what you need are listed below, but the query won't work if the table does not exist in your database.

Comment: I’m voting to close this since there is not enough information to reproduce the error. If the only issue is that OP forgot to create the table, that’s another good reason for closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL (as the question was originally tagged), you can use use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to return one row:

```
SELECT CUST_ID, COUNT(CUST_ID) AS C
FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
GROUP BY CUST_ID
ORDER BY C DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In the event of duplicates, this will return an arbitrary customer.  If you want all of them, use `RANK()`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT CUST_ID, COUNT(*) AS C,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
      GROUP BY CUST_ID
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to return one row (analogous to `LIMIT` in the MySQL example).

Comment: while using  limit it throws error as "LIMIT 1
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: @GAURAVSharma . . . MySQL **does not generate** Oracle errors.  You question was tagged MySQL.  I fixed the tag and adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@GAURAV Sharma You don't need to use `HAVING`, just use an `ORDER BY` statement and `LIMIT 1`:

EDIT NOTE: since the original question pointed to MySQL that is what this answer is applicable to.

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
    COUNT(CUST_ID) AS C
FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
GROUP BY CUST_ID
ORDER BY c DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In oracle 12c and higher, you can use **row limiting clause** and also handle the duplicate maximum as following:

```
SELECT CUST_ID, 
       COUNT(CUST_ID) AS CNT
  FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
GROUP BY CUST_ID
ORDER BY CNT DESC
FETCH FIRST RIW WITH TIES;
```

Here, `WITH TIES` will give you multiple `cust_id` if they have same count (which is maximum).